# vba simple login with username and password written in Sheet1

Tags: vba, authentication

I have a simple login form 
[image: login_form]

I want to be able to connect the list of users that I written in my excel sheet. 
[image: excel_sheet_containing_users]

I want also to have a 3 tries only attempt if possible..

This is for my programming project in school.

I was able to write the basic code for static username and password

here's the code:

```
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()

If TextBox1.Text = "abc" And TextBox2.Text = "123" Then

MsgBox "Welcome!!!", vbOKOnly

Else

MsgBox "Incorrect entry...", vbCritical

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you have a worksheet with the logins in a table (Column A: Username, Column B: Password) and you want the code to compare whether the user enters a combination of values in the appropriate text boxes which exists in the table. Essentially, `TextBox1` must contain a value found in Column 1 of the worksheet, and if it does then the value of `TextBox2` must be the same as the corresponding password in Column B.

One approach would be to do it so that, when the user presses the "Login" button `cmdLogin`, the code finds the username in Column A, and tests the value in the corresponding row of Column B against the contents of TextBox2. So, within your `Click` routine:

```
If l >= 3 then Exit Sub 'I'll come back to this after the code section

Dim UserRange as Range, x as Range 'This creates a Range object which represents the UserName column (A) and a 'utility' Range object which we can use
Dim LIMatch as Boolean 'A true/false indicator we can use to determine a correct login

Set UserRange = Sheets("Logins").Range("A:A") 'Assigns the column on your Login sheet to our declared range

'This next bit goes through the column and looks for the username, and checks it against the password in the same stage
For Each x in UserRange.Cells
    If x.Value = TextBox1.Text then
        If x.Offset(0, 1) = TextBox2.Text then
            MsgBox "Welcome"
            l = 0
            LIMatch = True
            Exit For 'Note the Exit For - without this, VBA will continue to look through the list of logins, which we don't want to do once we've found a match
        ElseIf IsEmpty(x) Then    ' If the cell is blank, it is the end of the username list, then exit the For loop
            Exit For
        Else
            MsgBox "Incorrect login"
            l = l + 1 'As above, I'll come back to this in a moment
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next x

If Not LIMatch Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Username", vbExclamation
End If
```

What you'll want to do is declare a public variable for l, which counts the login attempts. Unlike declaring a variable in a sub (`Dim l as Integer` for example), a Public variable will store its value outside the `Click` routine. If you declared it within your routine, each time the user clicked the login button, the value would be reset to 0 and they'd be able to keep trying a login.

Note the line at the start of the code which says `If l >= 3 then Exit Sub` - this reads the value of l from previous attempts and if it is 3 or more it will exit the routine entirely, preventing the user from trying another login.

This should give you a good framework to work from, and show you how to use iterative loops and variables which are very important and useful in any coding language.

Comment: SlashnBurn92 thank you for this one..I'll try this when I get to my computer later @ 10:30 EST.

Comment: No worries @FrozenBlood - I have just made a small edit, since I realised that I'd assigned the whole column ("A:A") to the UserRange - there would be a lot of empty cells that the code would go though in this method, so I've added: "ElseIf IsEmpty(x) Then Exit For", which will stop the loop if the cell is blank.

Comment: Hi SlashnBurn92 it's now working.  Thank you so much. I will have to study and learn the code and will add more field in excel whether a user is admin or just an ordinary user..more power to you.

Comment: Glad to be able to help @FrozenBlood. Enjoy your coding!

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake in the code, every time you type a wrong username or password, the counter is reset, this is caused by I = 0, remove that, then it'll be running